# How can I improve a search using strtok() function?

Tags: c++

I have a file "Shalespeare_Hamlet.txt" and it contains

> Hamlet, some text, Hamlet, SAMPLE TEXT.

A programm have to search the number of occurrences of words in the text.
How can i improve my code using strtok()?

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
const int len = 101;
char word[len], line[len];
cout << "Word: ";
cin >> word;

int l_word = strlen(word); 
ifstream fin("Shakespeare_Hamlet.txt"); 
if (!fin) {
    cout << "Error! Can't open the file.";
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}

int count = 0;
while (fin.getline(line, len)) { 
    char *p = line; 
    while (p = strstr(p, word)) {
        char *c = p; 
        p += l_word; 
        if (ispunct(*p) || isspace(*p) || (*p == '\0')) count++;
    }
}
cout << "Count of words: " << word << ": " << count << endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Rather than focusing on `strtok` (your current solution), why not tell us what problem you *actually* want to solve (so we may possibly suggest better solutions)?

Comment: `strtok()` should be the last resort.  You're using C++, not low-level C.

Comment: "How can I improve a search using strtok() function?" You can improve your code by using `std::string::find()`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie OP is using C with classes ^^ at least he doesn't `while(!fin.eof())`

Comment: I have a task to change the code using only `strtok()`

Comment: @AlexDisander Then you have either a delusional task or a misunderstanding.

Comment: @AlexDisander Stupid, arbitrary restrictions like that should (IMHO) be disregarded.

Comment: @AlexDisander So Swordwish is right -- you are learning `C` with some C++ syntax thrown in.

Comment: @AlexDisander -- `strtok` has many issues.  1) It destroys the original input string, and 2) It uses a static buffer, thus cannot be used if you have 2 or more `strok`'s going on in a nested loop or in a multithreaded program.  Even in a class on `C`, the teacher shouldn't be using this function, or at least point out its flaws.

Comment: Don't call it an improvement, because it isn't. It's satisfying your school requirements. Not the same thing.

Comment: @AlexDisander -- Also, what exactly is the definition of a "word"?  Is "123" a word?  How about "car4"?  Is that a word?  You need to clarify what is meant by "word" in your assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely redid the code hope that help
    using namespace std;

```
int main() {
ifstream fin("Shakespeare_Hamlet.txt");
if (!fin) {
    cout << "Opening error!!!\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

fin.seekg(0, ios::end);  
long length = fin.tellg();  
char *file = new char[length + 1];
fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);  
fin.read(file, length);  

int k = 0;
char* arr[50000];
char* str;
str = strtok(file, "\n ,.-!?:;");

while (str != NULL) {
    arr[k] = str;
    k++;
    str = strtok(NULL, "\n ,.-!?:;");
}

char word[20];
cout << "Enter word: ";
gets_s(word); 
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    if (strcmp(arr[i], word) == 0) {
        count++;
    }
}
cout << "Count of words: " << word << " : "<< count << endl;

delete[] file;
fin.close();
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You forgot as punctuation the quotation mark(s), bracket, etc. etc.  It would be easier to remove the punctuation marks first (replace each with spaces by calling `ispunct()` to test the character), and then go over the adjusted input a second time to extract the words.  Then the call to `strtok` would just need `' '` as the delimiter instead of a long stream of punctuation characters.

Comment: Also, if you look at [std::ispunct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct), you will see that using the default `C` locale, the punctuation characters are `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_``{|}~`.  So your solution is not complete, since the OP explicitly uses `ispunct` in their post to determine if a character is a punctuation.

Comment: Also, there is a problem with part words, for example: "SHamlet" will be considered  also, when you're looking for "Hamlet", in addition you're not cleaning white spaces such as `'\t'` and `'\r'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "improve" the program with `strtok` in C++ when there are better facilities like `std::string` and iostreams to solve the job.

Comment: how does that answer the question?

Comment: @Fureeish I regarded the implementation to be very C-style have and unsecure (doesn't handle lines or words over 100 characters long). Hinting at string and iostream usage to solve it better.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't be working properly in several cases:

- If the searched word is in position in line which is split between two gets, for example the word "Hamlet" started in char position 98 in the line and split to "Ham" and "let".
- If there is punctuation in the beginning of the word, like "Hamlet... you only check the end of the string but not the beginning.

I think your algorithm should be as follows:

1. Read whole line into a `std::string` using `std::getline`
2. Remove all punctuation from the line,
3. Use std::istringstream to split line into words.
4. For each word check if equal to input word, and if so increment count.

#### For example:

```
std::string line;
//read whole line to std::string 
while (std::getline(fin, line)) 
{ 
   std::string result;
   //remove punctuation and copy to result
   std::remove_copy_if(line.begin(), line.end(), std::back_inserter(result), std::ptr_fun<int, int>(&std::ispunct) );
   //use string stream to parse line without punctuation 
   std::istringstream istr(result);
   std::string str;
   while(istr>>str)
   {
      if(word==str)
      {
        count++;
      }
   }
}
```